# Node.js global variables and functions with square brackets - why does this work?

Tags: javascript, node.js, variables, brackets

I have module that returns an object to a callback with the structure of the following pseudocode:

```
module.exports=function(){

global.foo=function(){
  var callbacks=Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments,1);
  var conf=arguments[0];
  return global[callbacks.shift()].apply(null,[conf,callbacks]);
 }

global.bar=function(){
  var callbacks=Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments,1);
  var conf=arguments[0];
  return global[callbacks.shift()].apply(null,[conf,callbacks]);
 }

// This one is where i ran into trouble
global.foobar=function(){
  var callbacks=Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments,1);
  var conf=arguments[0];
  // right here
  if(callbacks.length===[].length){
     return global[callbacks.shift()].apply(null,[conf,callbacks]);
 }
}
var conf={'pseudo':'object'};   
return global['foo'](conf,'foo','bar','foobar');
}
```

Everything works fine until `foobar`, and what happens is that when I get down to checking if there are anymore callbacks - because if their are, I want to call them - `callbacks.length` is 1 at this point.  This didn't make sense to me, and I discovered that at that point `callbacks` actually equaled `[[]]`.  I don't know why this is getting returned, so I guess I have two questions. Can anyone see why `callbacks` is equal to `[[]]`?

What I discovered along the way is that when using Strings called as functions in the global namespace - as in `var bar='foo'`; `global[bar]()` calls `global.foo()` -  multiple brackets are ignored.  So for example, `global[[[[[[['foo']]]]]]] === global['foo']`.  Also weirdly enough (at least to me), the following:

```
// With 
global.bar='foo';
global.foo=function(){return true;}
//the following
global[global[bar]]()
// throws a TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

None of that makes sense to me.

I recognize that this question ends up asking three questions, and is a bit disorganized, but frankly I'm a bit confused, and I'm not really sure how I want to ask what I want to know, so I just said everything.

My main questions is regarding the multiple brackets, and why that works.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> My main questions is regarding the multiple brackets, and why that
>   works.

The multiple brackets works only because it's trying to do a string conversion to get a property name.  So, no matter how many nested arrays you have, it ends up calling `.toString()` on each array and since the inner array only has a single item that has a string in it, multiple `.toString()` calls just end up resolving to the inner string.

Here's a demo of the same concept in a browser:

```js
window.foo = "hi"
document.write(window[[[[["foo"]]]]]);
```

For some further explanation:

```
["foo"].toString() === "foo";
```

So, then:

```
[["foo"].toString()].toString() === "foo"
```

But, if the outer `.toString()` is there, it is already driving things to a string so you can remove the inner `.toString()` and thus you get:

```
[["foo"]].toString() === "foo"
```

And, you can then nest it as many levels as you want as long as something on the outer level is driving it to a string.

And, since property names are always strings, when you do:

```
global[[[[[[['foo']]]]]]]
```

You're ultimately asking for a property name that can be looked up on the `global` object and since the property name is a string, that calls `.toString()` on the outer array.  When the outer array goes to convert it's only item to a string, it asks that one item to convert itself to a string so this:

```
global[[[[[[['foo']]]]]]]
```

turns into this:

```
global[[[[[[['foo'].toString()].toString()].toString()].toString()].toString()].toString()]
```

Which hopefully explains why you end up with nothing more than this in the end:

```
global["foo"]
```

---

FYI, if you look at the ES5/ES6 spec for `Array.prototype.toString()`, it ends up calling `array.join()` which for a single element array just ends up doing a `.toString()` on that single element which is how it causes all the nested arrays to just call `.toString()` on themselves.  The outer array calls `.toString()` on the first nested array which called `.toString()` on it's single item which is the next nested array and so on until it finally gets to the inner string which is returned back from all the `.toString()` calls.  And, it matters not how many arrays deep it is nested.

Spec reference for `Array.prototype.toString()`: http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-array.prototype.tostring

Spec reference for `Array.prototype.join()` which is called by `Array.prototype.toString()`: http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-array.prototype.join

---

In your other scenario here:

```
// With 
global.bar='foo';
global.foo=function(){return true;}
//the following
global[global[bar]]()
// throws a TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

> None of that makes sense to me.

Here's what is going on in `global[global[bar]]()` one piece at a time:

`bar` resolves to the string `'foo'`.

So, `global[bar]` resolves to `global['foo']` which is your function.

But, then you try to do another global reference on it like this `global[global[bar]]`, then you are essentially trying to do:

```
global[yourfunction]
```

or

```
global[global.foo]
```

That will try to convert yourfunction to a string and look up that property on the `global` object.  That will be `undefined`.  So, you will then try to do `undefined()` which is a TypeError because `undefined` is not a function.

What will work in this case is just:

```
global[bar]()
```